# Removing links from posts in WordPress

Tags: links, sql, posts

I have few blogs for some clients. I need to remove links to one of my clients blogs in all posts. Just to be clear I need to remove links and my keyword should stay like it is.

I found [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-remove-links-from-posts/installation/), but it removes all links.

I need to remove all links just for one client, and links for other clients should stay unchanged.

Is there any way using SQL statements? I need solution to recognize link no matter what the keyword is and to remove `href` text leaving keyword unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

A find and replace plugin that searches the database such as [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/installation/) should help.

I don't think it will be able to automate the whole process, but should speed it up somewhat.